Orbiting charged bodies (e.g., accelerated electron in Rutherford model)
We know that if the Rutherford Model were correct, the electron would radiate energy and ultimately collapse into the nucleus with a spiral shaped trajectory. How do we determine the equation of trajectory for this and what would the equation of motion be along the radial direction. Would be anything similar to $\frac{Z^2 e^2}{4\pi\epsilon r^2} = m\frac{d^2 r}{dt^2} - m\omega^2 r$. And how do we incorporate the larmor formula into the equation along the radial direction.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70915/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/462578/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99285/2451 and links therein.

You can obtain a differential equation for $r$ using energy conservation. Express the total (kinetic plus potential) energy in terms of $r$; then equate its rate of decrease to the power being radiated away according to the Larmor formula, expressed in terms of $r$. Solving this will let you determine the collapse time. The approximation you’re making here is that the orbit stays nearly circular, but you can show that the shrinkage in radius per revolution is indeed small.

This is a common homework problem so I don’t want to write an answer with the details.

How do we incorporate the $\frac{d^2 r}{dt^2}$ term

When you deal with energy conservation, you don’t have an $\ddot r$ term.

What will be the equation of motion along the radial direction in this case then?
